# Possible to get access token on behalf on user without MS Library in Razor?

Tags: c#, azure, razor, graph

I am writing a Razor page application that get's the users data in Azure AD in the form of a HTTP GET call.

However, most of the documentation I found says to use the MS GRAPH library- is there a way to get the access token on behalf of the user with just standard HTTP?

I am not sure how to get the prompt to log into Office365 to show up from my razor pages application.

Answer (score 1):

You could get access token with [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

Get an authorization code in browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client-id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri in azure portal}
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

Get access token with the previous code:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id={client-id}
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&code={code from previous step}
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri in azure portal}
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

You will obtain the `upn`(The username of the user) and others after decoding the [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens). If you have the required [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) of MS Graph, you could also get the details of user with the API.